# persist in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a entity in controller:

```
$maxPrdObject  =   $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getRepository('PhebeeBundle:Product')->findOneById($max);

    if(is_object($maxPrdObject))
    {
        echo('object');
    }else
    {
    echo('not');
    }
```

This maxPrdObject is a object

When I do:

```
$this->em->persist($composition->setProductFather($maxPrdObject));
```

Response is NULL

```
 if ( ! is_object($entity)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(gettype($entity));
    }
```

This is an object but its value is null!

Comment: `$entity` is never set in your code example. Try also to separate your `persist` operation in 2 steps: `$composition->setProductFather($maxPrdObject); $this->em->persist($composition);`

Comment: I just wanna point out that "getEntityManager" is deprecated since Symfony 2.1. You should use getManager instead

Comment: Error: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given    I do:                                                $composition->setProductFather($maxPrdObject); 
  $composition->setProductSon($sonObject); 
  $this->em->persist($composition);

Comment: it's ok I have my response ;)